# Another PHP fatal error

Tags: php

Same site, different problem... It worked fine for a couple of minutes, but now I get this...

```
Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required  
'/home/retrorea/public_html/tradepost/includes/messages.english.php.inc.php'  
(include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in 
/home/retrorea/public_html/tradepost/includes/messages.inc.php on line 50
```

I havn't changed anything except for that. Here is line `50`:

`require($include_path.'messages.'.$language.'.inc.php');`

And here's the whole thing:

```
<?#//v.3.2.5
if(!defined('INCLUDED')) exit("Access denied");
#///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#// COPYRIGHT 2007 Phpauction.net ALL RIGHTS RESERVED //
#///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/** *************************************************************
* NOTE: Language management
*/

if(!empty($_GET[lan])) {
    $language = $_GET[lan];
    $_SESSION['language'] = $language;

    #// Set language cookie
    setcookie("USERLANGUAGE","",time()-3600);
    setcookie("USERLANGUAGE",$_GET[lan],time()+31536000,"/");
} elseif(isset($_SESSION['language'])) {
    $language = $_SESSION['language'];
} elseif(empty($_SESSION['language']) && !isset($_COOKIE['USERLANGUAGE'])) {
    $language = $SETTINGS['defaultlanguage'];
    $_SESSION['language'] = $language;

    #// Set language cookie
    setcookie("USERLANGUAGE","",time()-3600);
    setcookie("USERLANGUAGE",$language,time()+31536000);
} elseif(empty($_GET[lan])) {
  if(isset($_COOKIE['USERLANGUAGE'])) {
    $language = $_COOKIE['USERLANGUAGE'];
  } else {
    $language = $SETTINGS['defaultlanguage'];
  }
} elseif(isset($_COOKIE['USERLANGUAGE'])) {
    $language = $_COOKIE['USERLANGUAGE'];
} elseif(strlen($_GET[lan]) > 2 ) {
    $language = $SETTINGS['defaultlanguage'];
} else {
    $language = $SETTINGS['defaultlanguage'];
} 
$language = str_replace('..','',addslashes(htmlspecialchars($language)));
#// If the user is logged in, update the user's record
#// This is used to send the e-mails in the user's language
if(isset($_SESSION['PHPAUCTION_LOGGED_IN'])) {
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM PHPAUCTIONXL_userslanguage WHERE user='".$_SESSION['PHPAUCTION_LOGGED_IN']."'");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO PHPAUCTIONXL_userslanguage VALUES(
                         '".$_SESSION['PHPAUCTION_LOGGED_IN']."',
                         '$language')");
}
if (!$language) $language = $SETTINGS['defaultlanguage'];
require($include_path.'messages.'.$language.'.inc.php');
/* **************************************************************/
?>
```

Comment: Note: I see a lot of `$_GET[lan]` in your code, and while this technically will work in PHP, it is a very bad practice. It should be `$_GET['lan']`

Comment: Dude - do you *have* a file on the server called "/home/retrorea/public_html/tradepost/includes/messages.english.php.inc.php"???

Answer (score 1):

The file you want to include is not found. Have you checked if the path to the file is correct?

And are you sure the file that you want to include is `messages.english.php.inc.php`? I think you would include `messages/english.php.inc.php`.

---

Also, why twice a .php extension?

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the URL structure. Look at this part

```
messages.english.php.inc.php
```

Try modifying:

```
$include_path.'messages.'
```

With:

```
$include_path.'messages/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have defined `$include_path`. You need to make sure the file definitely exists before referencing it.

You might also want to use `include` instead of `require`:

> ```
> include() generates a warning, but the script will continue execution
> require() generates a fatal error, and the script will stop
> ```

Read about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp).